# Transforming every n rows of pandas Series into n columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a pandas Series like:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | -1175 |
| 2020-01-02 | -475 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1945 |
| 2020-01-06 | -1295 |
| 2020-01-07 | -835 |
| 2020-01-08 | -785 |
| 2020-01-09 | 895 |
| 2020-01-10 | -665 |

into a pandas DataFrame like:

| date | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | -1175 | -475 | 1945 | -1295 | -665 |
| 2020-01-02 | -475 | 1945 | -1295 | -835 | -785 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1945 | -1295 | -835 | -785 | 895 |
| 2020-01-06 | -1295 | -835 | -785 | 895 | -665 |

Every 5 (or n) rows of the Series forms one row in the DataFrame.

Sample data along with my current (ugly but working) code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
srs = pd.Series(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01",end="2020-1-10",freq="B")), 
                data=[-1175,-475,1945,-1295,-835,-785,895,-665])
n = 5
df = pd.concat({i: srs.shift(-i) for i in range(n)}, axis=1).dropna()
df = df[range(n)]
df.index = df.index.droplevel(level=0)
```

I was wondering if there is a better/neater/nicer way to do this?

Comment: `pd.concat([s.shift(-n) for n in range(5)],axis=1).iloc[:4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) from `numpy`:

```
n = 5
v = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(srs.to_numpy(), n)
df = pd.DataFrame(v, index=srs.index[:v.shape[0]])
```

`df`:

```
               0     1     2     3    4
2020-01-01 -1175  -475  1945 -1295 -835
2020-01-02  -475  1945 -1295  -835 -785
2020-01-03  1945 -1295  -835  -785  895
2020-01-06 -1295  -835  -785   895 -665
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

srs = pd.Series(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
    pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-1-10", freq="B")
), data=[-1175, -475, 1945, -1295, -835, -785, 895, -665])

n = 5
v = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(srs.to_numpy(), n)
df = pd.DataFrame(v, index=srs.index[:v.shape[0]])

print(df)
```